# Custom Angular2 Decorators for creating URLSearchParams

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-http

I'm creating an api service using angular 2 and created some decorators to help simplify the class interface a bit with some reusable functionality.

I want all of my service methods to take in a request object map that mirrors the http request's query parameters.

For example:

```
const request: SomeInterface = {
    param: 'value',
    otherParam: 'otherValue',
};
```

Would be passed into a class method that would use those key/value pairs as the query string parameters in an http request.

In it's simplest form, I want something like this to happen. This example will not execute because SomeInterface is not the type that Angular expects for the search property.

```
public getSomething(search: SomeInterface) {
    this.http.get(url, {
        search: search,
    });
}
```

I have created two decorators that accomplish transforming an object into an instance of `URLSearchParams`.

```
import { URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';

export function UrlSearchParams() {
    return function UrlSearchParams(target: any, methodName: string, index: number) {
        const metadataKey = `__urlSearchParams_${methodName}__`;
        target[metadataKey] = [index];
    };
};

export function NgServiceMethod() {
    return function NgServiceMethod(target, methodName, descriptor) {

        if (!descriptor) {
            descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, methodName);
        }
        const originalMethod = descriptor.value;

        descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
            const metadataKey = `__urlSearchParams_${methodName}__`;
            const parameter = target[metadataKey];
            const searchParams = new URLSearchParams();
            const request = args[parameter];

            for (const key in request) {
                if (request.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    searchParams.set(key, key);
                }
            }
            args[parameter] = searchParams;

            return originalMethod.apply(this, args);
        };

        return descriptor;
    };
};
```

Here's an example of it in action.

```
import { NgServiceMethod, UrlSearchParams } from '../shared/express/url-search-params.decorator';
import * as process from 'process';
import { SubmissionsRequest } from './submissions-request.model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, URLSearchParams, Headers } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class SubmissionsApiService {

    private submissionsApiUrl: string = '/social-submissions';

    constructor(private http: Http) { ; }

    @NgServiceMethod()
    public listSubmissions( @UrlSearchParams() submissionsRequest: SubmissionsRequest) {
        const headers = new Headers({
            'X-API-KEY': process.env.SUBMISSIONS_API_KEY,
        });

        return this.http.get(this.submissionsApiUrl, {
            search: submissionsRequest as URLSearchParams,
            headers: headers,
        });
    }
}
```

This works great. However there are a couple of nit-picky things I'm struggling with.

1. I want the service method signature to accept a parameter with the interface of the request object. In the case of the working example, an instance of `SubmissionsRequest`. Unfortunately, what's actually being passed the function is an instance of `URLSearchParams` because it's being replaced by the `UrlSearchParams` decorator.

   2. Because of the above, I have to cast `submissionsRequest` to `URLSearchParams` when I use it in the actual `http.get` call.

Everything works, however it's misleading because I'm saying that `submissionsRequest` is of type `SubmissionsRequest` in the method signature, but the reality is that it is of type `URLSearchParams`.

I guess I don't want consumers of the service to have to worry about passing in an instance of `URLSearchParams` and would prefer to do that work in the service, but I also don't want my service method to make use of the wrong type.

Any advice or ideas on how to reconcile this?